# How do I enter a loop in another loop?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

```
#include<iostream>
#include<iomanip>
using namespace std;


 int main()
{
int employeeNum = 0;            int totalEmployees  = 0;
double hourlyRate   = 0.0;          double totalhoursWork   = 0.0;
double hoursWork    = 0.0;          double totalnetPay      = 0.0;
double grossPay     = 0.0;          double averagehoursWork = 0.0;
double netPay       = 0.0;   double totalwithHoldings = 0.0;
double withHoldings = 0.0;          double overTime         = 0.0;
                                    int x                   = 0;




    while(employeeNum!= 9999)
     {
        cout <<" Enter Employee Number  (9999 to Stop):";
        cin >> employeeNum;
        if(employeeNum ==9999)
        break; 
        cout <<"Enter hourly rate:";
        cin >> hourlyRate;
        cout <<"Enter hours worked:";
        cin >> hoursWork;
        cout <<"Employee Number:"<<employeeNum << endl;
        if(hoursWork <= 40)
        {
            grossPay= hoursWork * hourlyRate;
    cout <<" Gross Weekly Pay=" << fixed <<setprecision(2)<< grossPay << endl;
        }
        else if (hoursWork > 40)
        {
            overTime = hoursWork-40;
            grossPay = (overTime * 1.5 + 40)* hourlyRate;


        cout <<" Gross Weekly Pay="<< fixed <<setprecision(2)grossPay << endl;

        }
        if( grossPay > 1000.00)
        {
            withHoldings= grossPay*0.28;

        }
        else  if( grossPay <= 1000.00)
        {
            withHoldings= grossPay*0.21;

        }

        netPay= grossPay-withHoldings;
        cout <<" Net Weekly Pay="<<fixed << setprecision(2) << netPay << endl;

        totalhoursWork+=hoursWork;
        totalnetPay+=netPay;
        totalwithHoldings+= withHoldings;
        averagehoursWork= totalhoursWork/totalEmployees;
        totalEmployees++;

            }       
    averagehoursWork= totalhoursWork/totalEmployees;
     for (int x = 1; x < 44; x = x + 1) 
         cout <<"*";
         cout << endl;



    cout <<"Total Employees Entered=" << totalEmployees << endl;
    cout <<" Total Hours Worked="<< fixed << setprecision(2) << totalhoursWork << endl;
    cout <<" Average Hours Worked="<< fixed << setprecision(2) << averagehoursWork << endl;
    cout <<" Total Net Pay="<<fixed << setprecision(2) << totalnetPay << endl;
    cout <<" TotalwithHoldings=" << fixed << setprecision(2)<< totalwithHoldings << endl;

     for (int x = 1; x < 44; x = x + 1) 
         cout <<"*";
         cout << endl;


system("pause");
return 0;
      }
```

Hourly rate must be greater than $7.25 and less than $100.00. Hours worked must be greater than 0 and less than 120. If the user enters invalid data display and appropriate error message and ask the user to re-enter. **What statement should I use for this portion and where should I put it??**

Comment: Instead of putting all the Codes, just explain with Simple code.

Comment: I think I mess up like that I have everything correct I just need to know a best place to enter it at

Answer (score 0):

You can use Cin and Cout for Input and output,, just use do While loop

```
 int employeeNum = 0;

            do
            {
                Console.WriteLine("enter Employee /Number 9999 to STOP");
                employeeNum = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

                if (employeeNum == 9999)
                    break;

                Console.WriteLine("enter hourly rate ");
                double hourRate = Double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());




            } while (employeeNum != 9999);
```

Comment: what are you initializing too??

Comment: Waht you mean.? I didn't get your comment

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
cout << "Enter hourly rate:";
cin >> hourlyRate;
while (hourlyRate <= 7.25 || hourlyRate >= 100) {
    cout << endl << "Reenter hourly rate (must be in (7.25 - 100))";
    cin >> hourlyRate;
}
```

But stackoverflow is not for others do you'r homework.

Comment: First line of my code is prompting user to enter some data. Second line getting user input. Third line starting the loop that runs while inputted data is incorrect. Fourth line (it's inside the loop) is displaying to user that data is incorrect and asks him to reenter data. Fifth line (it's inside the loop too) is getting user input for new data. You should learn c++ before writing code or asking questions on stackoverflow.

Comment: So basically I do the same for hoursWork??